# (jQuery or JS) Show when display=none

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm working on a html page that shows some description when a button is clicked, and hide the others description.

```html
<button onclick="showdescript()">Show Description 1</button> 
<button onclick="showdescript()">Show Description 2</button> 
<button onclick="showdescript()">Show Description 3</button> 

<p id="description1"> Desription 1</p>
<p id="description1"> Desription 2</p>
<p id="description1"> Desription 3</p> 

<script>
function showdescript(this) {

var display = document.getElementById(this).style.display;

if (display == none)
 {
  document.getElementById(this).style.display = block;
 } 

else {
  display = none;
}

}

</script>
```

I would be grateful if anyone could help!!!

Comment: document.getElementById() needs an Id in parenthesis, not 'this'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code is that there is no relationship between your `<button>` elements and the `<p>` element that they should be targetting. All you need is to pass the ID as an argument to `showdescript()`, and then use it to target the correct element.

You can then use `classList` to toggle classes to show/hide the `<p>` elements:

```js
function showdescript(id) {
  const otherEls = document.querySelectorAll('.target');
  const targetEl = document.getElementById(id);
  
  otherEls.forEach(el => {
    if (el !== targetEl)
      el.classList.remove('show');
    else
      el.classList.add('show');
  });
}
```

```css
.target {
  display: none;
}

.target.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showdescript('description1')">Show Description 1</button>
<button onclick="showdescript('description2')">Show Description 2</button>
<button onclick="showdescript('description3')">Show Description 3</button>

<p class="target" id="description1"> Desription 1</p>
<p class="target" id="description2"> Desription 2</p>
<p class="target" id="description3"> Desription 3</p>
```

However, the ideal solution is to avoid inline JS altogether. This can be done using `addEventListener()`:

```js
function showdescript(id) {
  const otherEls = document.querySelectorAll('.target');
  const targetEl = document.getElementById(id);
  
  otherEls.forEach(el => {
    if (el !== targetEl)
      el.classList.remove('show');
    else
      el.classList.add('show');
  });
}

document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => showdescript(btn.dataset.target));
});
```

```css
.target {
  display: none;
}

.target.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button data-target="description1">Show Description 1</button>
<button data-target="description2">Show Description 2</button>
<button data-target="description3">Show Description 3</button>

<p class="target" id="description1"> Desription 1</p>
<p class="target" id="description2"> Desription 2</p>
<p class="target" id="description3"> Desription 3</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.show-description').forEach((button, index) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.querySelectorAll('.description').forEach((desc, i) => {
            desc.style.display = (i === index) ? 'block' : 'none';
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.description {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="show-description">Show Description 1</button> 
<button class="show-description">Show Description 2</button> 
<button class="show-description">Show Description 3</button> 

<p class="description"> Desription 1</p>
<p class="description"> Desription 2</p>
<p class="description"> Desription 3</p>
```